# android http post as a service

Tags: android, service, background, httpclient

can any one please tell me how to make this code work in the background and what is the difference when i make the code work in the background as in "do in background" and a service
and which approach should i take

thanks to all in advance

this is the code:

```
public void  SticketFunction(double book, double libadd, long time){
        Log.v("log_tag", "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SticketFunction()");
        //HttpClient
        HttpClient nnSticket = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //Response handler
        ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();

        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://www.books-something.com");


        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("book", book+""));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("libAss", libass+""));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Time", time+""));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "jack"));
            //Encode and set entity
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
            //Execute 
            //manSticket.execute(postMethod);
            String response =Sticket.execute(postMethod, res).replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>","");
            if (response.equals("Done")){

                //Log.v("log_tag", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! SticketFunction got a DONE!");

            }
            else Log.v("log_tag", "!!!!!!!?????????? SticketFunction Bad or no response: " + response);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            //Log.v("log_tag", "???????????????????? SticketFunction Client Exception");
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //Log.v("log_tag", "???????????????????? IO Exception");
        } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a service for this. I believe you could use the AsyncTask if you don't want to block your application while doing the HTTP request. It provides a handy interface for showing results on the ui.

Another option is using the Handler class.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of running a task in a `Service` is that it is not destroyed if the user backs out of the calling `Activity`.

You could look into extending [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and implementing [onHandleIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29), which automatically does work on a separate thread.

When using a `Service` (or `IntentService`)in this situation, you would pass the `NameValuePair` values in a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). You would also need to save the `Response` data to persistent storage (database, preferences, etc), for later retrieval in an `Activity`.

Alternatively, you can run an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in a regular `Service` (implementing `onStartCommand`), or in the calling `Activity`.